# Confluence is very slow behind firewall

Tags: linux, apache, firewall, confluence

I've installed Confluence on Debian Linux 7.0. It runs on 8081 port (for connector, 8091 is used as TomCat server port). I've configured Apache to act as reverse proxy and serve on `https://confluence.<mydomain>.com` (SSL is configured on Apache side).

The configuration worked perfect unless I set up firewall rules. It still works as expected but became extremely slow (memory and CPU utilisations are low). Switching firewall off brings the performance back to normal. The set of firewall rules for IPv4 is:

```
*filter

-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Accept all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# Allows SSH connections
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow all HTTP and HTTPS connections
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

IPv6 traffic is completely disabled:

```
*filter

-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP

COMMIT
```

I'm using Oracle JVM (1.7), startup options are configured in the following way:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

Confluence version is "Confluence 5.4.2 - Standalone (TAR.GZ Archive)", license is Starter (10 users). Database is locally installed PostreSQL.

Anyone has an idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: My guess would be that your firewall rules don't allow DNS lookups and that leads to timeouts with name resolution.

Comment: I'm allowing all outgoing traffic by saying -P OUTPUT ACCEPT. Just checked this by connecting to Linux box over SSH and browsing to a website with lynx - hostname was resolved immediately.

Comment: If you are going to DROP IPv6 connections you should use this Java option: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  The JVM (at least for OpenJDK) checks if IPv6 is enabled. If this works for you I will write the answer explaining this behaviour with the source code for OpenJDK (the Oracle implementation should be more or less the same)

Comment: The JVM flag itself did not help, but overall concept was right - there is not reason to drop all IPv6 traffic. I've allowed outbound/loopback/established IPv6 traffic and the performance came back. It looks like the problem lies in the area Confluence-PostgreSQL connection where IPv6 is used. Also it is worth mentioning, if I were to set REJECT instead of DROP, I wouldn't get the problem since protocol feedback would come immediately. Thanks for your help.